# P. Hall's paper where he arrives at the Möbius Inversion Formula

Tags: reference-request

I read on Wikipedia page on Möbius Inversion Formula that "the statement of the general Möbius inversion formula [for partially ordered sets] was first given independently by Weisner (1935) and Philip Hall (1936); both authors were motivated by group theory problems." I was wondering if anyone knows how to find the original papers of Weisner and P. Hall where they arrive at this formula, and if an English translation at all exists. I would appreciate it a lot. Thanks.

Comment: If you click on the reference wikipedia gives for that statement, it takes you to an article from the American Mathematical Monthly. If you read that article, you'll find the exact references. They're both in English.

Comment: Got it, thank you!